# How can I iterate over all unique pairs of entries in an object?

Tags: javascript, iteration, javascript-objects

I currently have an array data structure that I iterate over like this, calling `foo` on each unique pair of elements.

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for(var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        foo(arr[i], arr[j]);
    }
}
```

However, I've realized that I'd rather use an object instead of an array, since I can then add and remove elements by name very easily.

However, I can't see an obvious way to iterate over such an object. The closest I can get is:

```
for(i in obj) {
    for(j in obj) {
        foo(obj[i], obj[j]);
    }
}
```

Obviously, this will do each pair twice, and even produce a pair of identical elements. Is there an easy way to iterate over an object in the same way as I do in the array in my first code sample?

#### Update:

Performance testing the solutions on [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/adjacent-pair-iteration).

Comment: If you want to iterate objects inside objects I guess the best option is to create a recursive function, there are some other example here in SO.

Comment: How about adding an `if (i < j)` condition in the inner loop? It's not the fastest solution, but I believe it could work.

Comment: @elclanrs: I'm not iterating recursively - I'm iterating over every possible combination of entries in an object/array. Eg, in the array `[1, 2, 3]`, I want to call `foo(1, 2)`, `foo(1, 3)`, and `foo(2, 3)`.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg; Yeah, that'd work! I just came up with that myself, but if you post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg that won't work in each case because the keys of an object don't have to be sorted and they don't have to be of the same data type as well.

Comment: @Jasd: They don't need to be sorted for that to work. All it does make sure that `foo(obj[a], obj[b])` and `foo(obj[b], obj[a])` are not both called (for constant `a`, `b`), since one must violate the condition `i < j`. And object keys are _always_ strings, so the comparison never fails.

Comment: @Eric you are right. But strings (object keys) are compared differently to integers (array keys) (e.g. "10" < "2" and 10 < 2 leads to a different result).

Comment: @Jasd: Nope, array keys are strings as well. Try doing a `for ... in` loop with an array. The keys you get are not integers, but strings.

Comment: No, what I'm trying to say is that @SimonAndréForsberg 's solution could behave differently. Imagine you have the keys "10" and "2". Iterating over an object with those keys would execute `foo("10","2")`. If you have an array with the keys from 0 to 10 `foo(10,2)` wouldn't be called but `foo(2,10)`. Depending on the implementation of foo this could be something different.

Comment: Ah, ok. I should have pointed out that `foo` is symmetrical, and does not care which order its arguments come in. Hence the requirement for unique pairs, not all pairs.

Comment: Ohh stupid me. I didn't know that array keys are also stored as strings. That makes my whole argument invalid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution that was at first written as a comment:

Add an `if (i < j)` condition in the inner loop. It might not be the best solution, but it would work as long as the foo function does the same thing for `foo(2, 10)` and `foo(10, 2)`:

```
for(i in obj) {
    for(j in obj) {
        if (i < j) {
            foo(obj[i], obj[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not the fastest? Does a string comparison cost more or less than a property lookup?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure at all if it is the fastest solution or not :) Edited that part. It might be both the easiest, most neat and fastest solution (in your case at least).

Comment: tbh, speed is not a great issue, since `foo` is orders of magnitude more expensive that the string comparison. Nevertheless, doing some performance tests at http://jsperf.com/adjacent-pair-iteration

Comment: This was more performant than looping all results. 2x faster in fact and it's cognitively easier to understand than some of the other responses.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand your question... maybe check to see if the value has already been visited by the outer loop?

```
var visited = {}
for(i in obj) {
    visited[i] = true;
    for(j in obj) {
        if(j in visited){ continue; }
        foo(obj[i], obj[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Object.keys() to get the list of keys out as an array:

```
keys = Object.keys();
for(i=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
    for(j=i+1;j<keys.length;j++) {
        foo(obj[keys[i]], obj[keys[j]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably better to store `Object.keys()` in a variable rather than evaluating it `n + 3*n*n` times

Comment: Why was my edit refused? Your code doesn't work like you put it. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe You can try unset used objects:

```
for(i in obj) {
    var a = obj[i];
    delete obj[i];
    for(j in obj) {
        foo(a, obj[j]);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bXcvb/

If you need to original obj in tact see: [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: **+1** for an interesting approach, but I'd rather not pull my object apart every time I iterate over it!

Comment: I am not sure if you can have performance and the neatness. It's either or... But thanks for the +1 :)

Comment: Yeah, but when you need to clone it, then its not so nice anymore: http://jsperf.com/adjacent-pair-iteration/2

Comment: Still, this could be good to know whenever you need to do a fast iteration over an object that's going to be deleted anyways... just gotta wait for that moment. I'm surprised to see that when copying the speed is about the same as my solution.

Comment: I think its the key assignment on objects (`obj[key] = ...`) that's so brutally expensive. If there was a deep memcopy in js, this could be improved a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can push the object keys into an array:

```
var obj_keys = [];
for (i in obj) {
  obj_keys.push(i);
}

for(i = 0; i < obj_keys.length; ++i) {
    for(j = i + 1; j < obj_keys.length; ++j) {
        foo(obj[obj_keys[i]], obj[obj_keys[j]]);
    }
}
```