# How to write a character matching algorithm in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Given this input `s1 = "dadxx"` `s2 = "ddxx"` I'd expect the output to contain a bunch of `a,b` pairs wherever each character in `s1` matched a character in `s2` and vice versa (duplicates allowed). Among those pairs would be `0,0` because `s1[0]` and `s2[0]` are both equal to `d`.

The problem is that my output doesn't contain `2,1` even though `s1[2]` and `s2[1]` are both equal to `d`.

Can someone fix my algorithm or make a better one?

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChefGabe/avc705zr/) if it helps.

Here's my code:

```
// For each char, see if other string contains it
s1 = 'dadxx'
s2 = 'ddxx'

matchChars(s1,s2)
matchChars(s2,s1)

function matchChars(a,b) {
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        found = b.indexOf(a[i])
        if (found >= 0) {
            if (a===s1) console.log(i,found)
            else console.log(found,i)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you split them into an array of characters, I think maybe an [array intersection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript) is what you are going for?

Comment: @CrayonViolent thanks but this more like an overachieving array intersection that finds all matches and returns their indices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem you're having is that you're only checking for a single match for `s1[i]` in `s2` by using `indexOf`. That will find the first index of a matched value, not every index.

If you instead iterate through both strings and compare every character, you get the result I think you're trying to achieve.

```
// Define strings
s1 = 'dadxx'
s2 = 'ddxx'

matchChars(s1,s2)
matchChars(s2,s1)

function matchChars(a,b) {
  // Convert strings to lower case for case insensitive matching
  // Remove if case sensitive matching required
  a = a.toLowerCase();
  b = b.toLowerCase();

  // Iterate through every letter in s1
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    // Iterate through every letter in s2
    for (j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
      // Check if the letter in s1 matches letter in s2
      if (a[i] === b[j]) {
        // Changed per request of OP
        (a === s1) ? console.log(i, j) : console.log(j, i);
        // console.log([i, j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Working JSBin example: https://jsbin.com/wecijopohi/edit?js,console

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks!!

Comment: Only issue is that there are duplicates.

Comment: Hm why did you delete your last comment then? (about false positives `1,0` and `1,2`)

Comment: I've just output the letters being matched with the index, and the letters were correct. I'm just looking at it again. https://jsbin.com/wecijopohi/edit?js,console

Comment: There's a mistake in it somewhere, because the index `1` in `a` should never be matched. But my code is showing that as a `d` instead of an `a`. Something peculiar is happening.

Comment: Ok feel free to make a new answer or revise. I'll wait.

Comment: I don't see any errors or duplicates in your code. You're just calling `matchChars` twice with swapped parameters.

Comment: D'oh. Everything is fine. I've just noticed the function is called twice with the string order switched!!! Ignore all previous comments.

Comment: It has been a long week. That's my excuse and I'm sticking to it.

Comment: Please revise your `console.log` line to this and I'll mark it correct: `if (a === s1) console.log(i, j);` `else console.log(j, i)`

Answer (score 1):

You say duplicates are allowed but not required. I'm submitting this as a more modern approach, not as a correction to the accepted solution, which looks good to me. https://jsfiddle.net/avc705zr/3/

```
match = (a, b) => {
  let re, match, matches = []
  a.split('').forEach((l, i) => {
    re = new RegExp(l, 'g')
    while ((match = re.exec(b)) != null) {
      matches.push([i, match.index])
    }
  })
  return matches
}
```

However, in my experience when you actually need functionality like this, you only need one of the strings to exhausted. In other words, you are looking for matches in string 2 of all instances in string 1 -- which is to say, *unique* characters in string 1. So a modification which might come up in the real world might instead be like:

```
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
  return this.filter(function (value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
  });
}

match = (a, b) => {
  let re, match, matches = []
  a.split('').unique().forEach(l => {
    re = new RegExp(l, 'g')
    while ((match = re.exec(b)) != null) {
      matches.push([l, match.index])
    }
  })
  return matches
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Another optimization (for your first answer) might be to only perform the comparison on [unique pairs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505286/how-can-i-iterate-over-all-unique-pairs-of-entries-in-an-object).